# How to easily identify dependent clause?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

From the following sentences, which sentence contains a dependent clause?

1. Before taking the exam, my nephew studied really hard.
2. I heard something strange when downloading some movies last night.
3. The operator directly input the data after knowing about the repaired system.
4. That my father has worked as a network designer for five years is true

Is option (1) the correct answer?

I'm a beginner in English and I got confused a lot when it comes to identifying dependent clauses.
I hope somebody can help. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us for each one what you think and why so people can help you better.

Comment: I've edited the post. I'm sorry I'm new to this website

Comment: A dependent clause is defined as *a group of words that contains a subject and verb but does not express a complete thought*. By implication, the subject in a dependent clause can't be the same thing as the *main* subject in a sentence containing a dependent clause (but I've no idea if there are *any* here). The only subjects in #1, #2, and #3 are "my nephew", "I", and "the operator". But #4 has as its "primary" subject the entire noun phrase *[the fact] that my father has worked as a network designer for five years*, and *within* that np is the "embedded" lower-level subject "my father".

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *Before* [*taking the exam,*] *my nephew studied really hard*.
>
> [2] *I heard something strange when* [*downloading some movies last night*].
>
> [3] *The operator directly input the data after* [*knowing about the repaired*
> *system*].
>
> [4] [*That my father has worked as a network designer for five years*] *is true.*

A dependent (usually subordinate) clause is one that is dependent on some other element in the sentence.

All your examples contain a dependent clause, each surrounded by square brackets.

In [1-3], the *ing* clauses are dependents of the prepositions "before", "when" and "after". In [4], the subordinate *that* clause is a dependent one by virtue of being a complement of the verb "be".

Note that traditional grammar takes "before", "when" and "after" as subordinating conjunctions; thus the clauses they introduce are subordinate , i.e. dependent ones.